# Why didn't Tsukasa kill Senku and his friends in episode 3?

Tags: dr.stone

In episode 3, Tsukasa had the chance of killing Senku and his friends, after Senku fired a sort of arrow at him and missed, but he left them alive.

Why didn't Tsukasa kill Senku and his friends in episode 3, when they are confronted, Senku tried to kill him , and Tsukasa clearly has no problem killing humans since he destroyed several humans turned into stone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tsukasa didn't kill Senku and his friends because he doesn't know how to revive humans. So otherwise he would be alone.